# Select records matching concat value of two fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, concatenation

Is there a way to do something like this on MongoDB?

```sql
select * from table where concat(field1, field2) = 'value'
```

To clarify, I have an array of full names, but the documents have firstname and lastname separate, so I want to do something like:

```sql
select * from table where concat(firstname, lastname) in ([ARRAY OF NAMES])
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can only do it with aggregation framework, not with regular find.

```
db.coll.aggregate({$project:{newField:{$concat:["$field1","$field2"]}}},
                  {$match:{newField:"value"}} 
);
```

Note that this will not be able to use any indexes, since there is no support for indexes on computed values in MongoDB (yet).

If you have an index on `field1` and you know how many characters you expect field1 to contribute to `value` you can improve performance of this aggregation like this:

```
db.coll.aggregate({$match:{field1:/^val/}},
                  {$project:{newField:{$concat:["$field1","$field2"]}}},
                  {$match:{newField:"value"}} 
);
```

where `val` is first part of "value" string (you must not compare more characters than the shortest possible value of `field1` though.

**EDIT** as of version 3.6 you can do this in find using the `$expr` expression:

```
db.coll.find({$expr:{$eq:["value", {$concat:["$field1", "$field2"]}]}})
```

Comment: Awesome, this is almost what I need: check my edit, how can I turn the $match into a "in (array)" ?

Comment: nvm, found the $in operator!

Comment: Chaining in mongodb aggregate is where it's at!

Comment: @AsyaKamsky - How to achieve this same functionality in C# using MongoDB.Drivers

Comment: Please ask C# as a separate question.

Comment: Can the `$expr` solution use index?

Comment: Like my answer says, there is no way to have index used on a computed expression.  $expr would be able to use index with $eq if it was comparison with a constant.

Comment: Tried to get a query to work for an hour, you're a champ, this helped solve it!

Comment: @Deleteman So how can one use the `$in` operator in this context? It needs the structure `{fieldname: {$in: [1,2,3]}}`, but in this case `fieldname` would have to be our `$concat` object, which (obviously) can't act as a key. How is this possible??

Comment: Use aggregation $in expression inside $expr

Comment: If you don't want just want to add this new field on top of all the other ones I would use $addFields instead of $project

Answer (score 7):

If the argument ($field1 or $field2) resolves to a value of null or refers to a field that is missing, $concat returns null.  Since mongoDB3.0, a new $ifNull is provided to check if the argument is null and provide an alternative

```
{ $ifNull: [ <expression>, <replacement-expression-if-null> ] }

db.coll.aggregate({$project:{newField:{$concat:[{$ifNull:["$field1",""]},{$ifNull:["$field2",""]}]}}},
              {$match:{newField:"value"}})
```

The results may not differ if we are using $match, but this results will vary if you want to use $regex.

Answer (score 1):

In Mongoose you can like that

```
let clause =  [                                               
            { $project: { name: { $concat: ["$first_name"," ","$last_name"]}}},
            { $match: { name: new RegExp("ab", 'i')}}                       
         ];                                                                             
Model.aggregate(clause)
```

OutPut will be like that

```
[
{
    "_id": "5911db2b9235272052fdd2e1",
    "name": "Ali Abbas"
},
{
    "_id": "5912f7dd8bdbc24aa37b5239",
    "name": "Ali Abad"
},
{
    "_id": "59229e0322abdb311818e419",
    "name": "Syed Ali Abbas Shah"
},
{
    "_id": "592837da188fa969cc135ddc",
    "name": "Abu Akbar"
}
```

]