# How to use a concatenation as the field name for the MongoDB $in operator?

Tags: mongodb, concatenation, string-concatenation

Assume I have a list of names and want to match documents which are not part of it:

```
{ firstname: { $not: { $in: ["Alice", "Bob"] } } }
```

But now I have to match against first name + last name (i.e. the given list is `["Alice Smith", "Bob Jones"]`).

I know I can concatenate the two fields easily like this:

```
{ $concat: ["$firstname", " ", "$lastname"] }
```

But how do I use this new "field" in the initial query like I used `firstname` there? Obviously, I can't just replace the object key with this expression.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24662504/3746543) is pretty close, but unfortunately it's missing the last piece of information on how exactly one uses that solution in the `$in` context. And since I think this is a general usage question but couldn't find anything about it (at least with the search terms I used), I'm opening this separate question.

Edit: If possible, I want to avoid using an aggregation. The query I'm looking for should be used as the `filter` parameter of [the Node driver's `deleteMany` method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Collection.html#deleteMany).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$expr`, and for not equal to use `$not` outer side of `$in`,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $not: {
          $in: [
            { $concat: ["$firstname", " ", "$lastname"] },
            ["Alice In wonderland", "Bob Marley"]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BU4AZAWiKr7)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion (and the much nicer last names :D), but is this also possible without an aggregation? I just realised I didn't specify this, so I updated my question.

Comment: I am not sure but you can try this main part in your query filter, like find() look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3v2acoyEPdm)

Comment: That works like a charm! Reading [the documentation of `$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) that makes perfect sense too, as the text "Allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language" defines that operator's purpose as precisely what I needed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you are really close.

You have to use an aggregate. It's a sequence of "stages" where in each stage you can transform the data and pass the result to the next stage.

---

Here is a solution; Try it [Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tAGeeBll4NN)

with a `$project` i create a new field `full_name` by using your `$concat`

Then with a `$match`, I use your condition `{ firstname: { $not: { $in: ["Alice", "Bob"] } } }` but I instead apply it to the newly created `full_name`

You can remove the `$match` in the mongoplayground and see what it does.

PS : there is a mongo operator `$nin` that does the combination of `$not` and `$in`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "full_name": {
        $concat: [
          "$firstname",
          " ",
          "$lastname"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      full_name: {
        $nin: [
          "Alice In wonderland",
          "Bob Marley"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Do I really _have_ to use an aggregate? I'm using aggregations regularly and would've been able to construct such a simple pipeline myself, but in this case I want to avoid it. Sorry for not specifying this initially; I updated my question accordingly.