# Concat first name and last name in where clause in laravel mongodb to search

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, mongodb, eloquent

I am trying concat first name and last name in Laravel but it's not working. i am using mongo db

i was tried this sql query but its not working

```
->orWhere(\DB::raw("CONCAT(`last_name`, ' ', `first_name`)"), 'LIKE', "%".$search."%");
```

can anyone find the alternate solution of concat in mongodb

Thank you in advance

Comment: what package are you using ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662413/select-records-matching-concat-value-of-two-fields-in-mongodb says it can't be done with a regular query. I don't know how to use that with Laravel's query builder, though

Comment: Hello @MoussabKbeisy We are using a mongo package for laravel jenssegers/mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do something like:

```
$full_name = explode(" ", $search);
$last_name  = $full_name[0];
$first_name = $full_name[1];
```

Then:

```
->orWhere(function($query){
  $query->where('last_name', $last_name)->where('first_name', $first_name);
});
```

Comment: hi @kapitan thank you it's working

Comment: glad to know its working, though you might want to full proof this further by adding the `trim()` function. `trim(explode(" ", $search))`, `trim($full_name[0])` and `trim($full_name[1])`.