# Search string contained between two fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm looking forward to a solution very similar to the one proposed in this question:
[Select records matching concat value of two fields in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662413/select-records-matching-concat-value-of-two-fields-in-mongodb)

I have two fields: `firstName` and `lastName`, and I want to search a string that can be contained in this two fields.
In that question I linked before I found this:

`db.coll.find({$expr:{$eq:["MY QUERY STRING", {$concat:["$firstName", "$lastName"]}]}})`

But this expression check for the exact match. I would like something like Sql: `%like% instead of` $eq`

So if I have a record like:

```
{
    "firstName": "Mario",
    "lastName": "Roberto Rossi"
}
```

I want to find that with a query string: `Mario Roberto`.
How can I change my query to solve this problem?

Comment: Is it full text search or find?

Comment: I would like to find a portion of text inside that two field. Something similar to a SQL  `%like%`

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      newField: {
        $concat: [
          "$firstName",
          " ",
          "$lastName"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      m: {
        "$regexMatch": {
          "input": "$newField",
          "regex": "mario robert",
          "options": "i"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      m: true
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fIMwKueQzsE)

You can simplify this. You can change regex as per your use-case.

You can check for atlas search if you are looking for search functionality in mongo.

Comment: It seems work! But it only gives me the `newField` and `_id` in the results. There's the possibility to have the entire object?

Comment: You can add it to the project stage i.e first stage like `firstName: 1, lastName: 1` or else replace `project` with `addFields`

Comment: maybe steve needs all this to a match? like [this](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=627a8f39ad87e9cf3a92942c)  ?

Comment: Yes @Takis That's the simplified version and his expected answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot both takis and gibbs! Your answers are perfect